# Is Layered navigation available in SOAP / REST API

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, rest-api, web-services

I'm building web services for an Android application, in that i need to provide an filter something similar to Layered navigation.

I've checked in Official Docs of REST and SOAP Web services, Layered navigation is not available in both.

Is it really not available or i didn't checked it properly ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct access to the layered nav from the SOAP and REST api, and you cannot check which attributes can be used in the layered nav with the default install.  Take for example the `catalogAttributeEntity` from the WSDL. It only returns a few details about the attributes.

```
<complexType name="catalogAttributeEntity">
    <all>
        <element name="attribute_id" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element name="code" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element name="type" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element name="required" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element name="scope" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </all>
</complexType>
```

You can try to extend this functionality to give you only the filtrable attributes and based on category or search results, but It's a long process.

if you manage to implement this, the rest should be easy, because you can supply filters to any product collection with SOAP or REST calls.

See this as example for soap: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.list.html

and this for rest: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html#RESTAPIIntroduction-Products

So to answer you question, The apis do not fully support layered nav but it can be achieved with some code.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for this ? [http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51795/get-second-level-of-layered-filter-attributes]http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51795/get-second-level-of-layered-filter-attributes